# Spring Cannot instantiate interface org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListene

Tags: spring

I have strange issue with my project because it works for Linux but the same config and code don't work at Windows platform;/

Error when i Try build it with Spring suite tool on windows:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot instantiate interface org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListener : org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:413)
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:392)
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getRunListeners(SpringApplication.java:378)
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:291)
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118)
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107)
>       at com.example.resty.RestyApplication.main(RestyApplication.java:10)
>   Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/aop/framework/AopProxyUtils
>       at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:154)
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:409)
>       ... 6 more
>   Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/aop/framework/AopProxyUtils
>       at org.springframework.context.event.AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster.addApplicationListener(AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster.java:105)
>       at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.(EventPublishingRunListener.java:56)
>       at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>       at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>       at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>       at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>       at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:142)
>       ... 7 more
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.aop.framework.AopProxyUtils
>       at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>       at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>       at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>       ... 14 more

My pom.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.example.test</groupId>
<artifactId>Demo</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>Resty</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.10.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```